# Flask app not displaying list as expected

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have an app that scrapes a website using beautiful soup. It returns the data in a table for me. I implemented a search bar using wtforms and a sqlite3 query.

[Web page sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xabE1.png)

This returns the data I want, but not how I want it. As soon as I submit the search it loads a list on a page instead of on the index.

[the results after search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NzHX.png)

This is my flask app (part of):

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    products = get_products()
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        item = '%' + form.searchFor.data + '%'
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM supplementInfo WHERE (name) LIKE (?)", (item,))
        search_results = c.fetchall()
        return str(search_results)

    return render_template('index.html', products=products, form=form)
```

And this is the html:

```
<div col-12 class="wrap">
        <div class="search">
            <form method="POST" action="/">
                {{ form.csrf_token }}
                {{ form.searchFor(class_="searchTerm") }}
                <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                    <i class="icon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="infoTable">
<table>
    {% for row in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
            <td> {{ row[1] }}</td>
            <td> {{ row[2] }}</td>
            <td> {{ row[3] }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>

</center>

<div>
    <table>
        {% for item in search%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I had to change the app to read as such:

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    products = get_products()
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        item = '%' + form.searchFor.data + '%'
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM supplementInfo WHERE (name) LIKE (?)", (item,))
        search_results = c.fetchall()
        return render_template('index.html', products=products, form=form, search_results=search_results)
    return render_template('index.html', products=products, form=form)
```

I realized I was returning the list instead of returning the template and passing it the list.